# SOes tendra el navbar que tiene la version original. (yo lo quiero)

Tags: discusión, barra-superior

Pues eso que he visto el nuevo navbar de SO y esta muy guay ademas de util sobre todo la disposicion del campo de buscar, entre otras cosas como las nuevas opciones de manera mas rapida, bueno un +10 para el equipo de diseño de SO.

https://stackoverflow.com/

P.D: Ya dije que yo tambien lo quiero.

Comment: Seguro que sí: en [so] es donde se hacen las pruebas. Si funcionan bien, se despliegan al resto de sitios. Aún recuerdo hace unos años cuando introdujeron esta barra negra superior que tenemos ahora... me hago viejo.

Comment: @fedorqui, a mi me gustaría que la nueva barra superior (navbar) tuviera el color negro que tiene la barra actual, por lo que leí, lo han hablado pero no hay una respuesta definitiva.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave para gustos colores XD a mi me gusta mas sin el negro, pero ya que estan podrian poner la opcion de personalizar el color para cada usuario, asi cada uno pone el que mas le apetezca, aunque en negro quizas tambien luzca muy bien. Saludos

Comment: Personalizar el color sería lo mejor. No a todos les gusta el color naranja en los bordes por ejemplo. El gris lo veo neutral. GitHub pasa de gris a negro y SO de negro a gris xD

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave pues aprovecha que está siendo discutido en Meta SO: [Top Navigation Update](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343653/1983854). Allí puedes presentar tus sugerencias y si convences a suficiente gente (especialmente a los desarrolladores) puede que se implemente.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [La navegación nueva se aplicará aquí muy pronto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1779/la-navegaci%c3%b3n-nueva-se-aplicar%c3%a1-aqu%c3%ad-muy-pronto) -- ¡olé, la tendremos!

Answer (score 3):

Al ver que se esta comentado sobre el color de la barra y gracias al link de [fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1410/soes-tendra-el-navbar-que-tiene-la-version-original-yo-lo-quiero?noredirect=1#comment3837_1410) puede ver la respuesta siguiente igual interese a otra gente que no hable ingles o por ejemplo que no la ha podido leer anteriomente (la traduccion no es muy buena pero creo que se entiende).

**[Steven Penny](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343106#343106)**

---

La nueva barra de navegación superior necesita un tema oscuro.

El equipo de diseño/moderación ha pasado al tema de color blanco/blanco, todo lo que puedo hacer es ayudar a la gente a obtener un tema oscuro.

A tal fin, se puede utilizar el complemento elegante ([Stylish add-on](//wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylish)) con el [tema oscuro de Dimitris's](//gist.github.com/g00glen00b/328bba7fdb392d3b8a7f2e6f7d468dbc):

> [image: alpha]

O [Steven’s dark theme](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/master/stylish/stackoverflow.css) con [reduced height](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341892):

> [image: bravo]

---

> P.D: Cierto es que esta respuesta no responde a la pregunta original,
>   la cual es repondida por [fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1410/soes-tendra-el-navbar-que-tiene-la-version-original-yo-lo-quiero?noredirect=1#comment-3827) en un comentario. Pero al ver
>   que en los comentario se esta generando interes en el color de la
>   misma y como se comenta al principio de esta respuesta, creo que no
>   esta demas poner una respuesta que trate el tema de los colores que ya
>   esta siendo tratado en SO y se estan aportando algunas soluciones/alternativas que podrian ser o no temporales.