# La navegación nueva se aplicará aquí muy pronto

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, barra-superior

Creo que todos se han dado cuenta ya que la navegación del sitio en inglés ha sido actualizada. Les comparto una imagen del nuevo "look..."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparte de la reputación presentada de forma patética, la organización del menú funciona muy bien.  Pronto tendremos esta navegación aquí también, menos los botones para *Jobs* y *Documentation*.

Comment: No se si alegrarme u horrorizarme. No se si la navegación nueva me gusta o me horroriza.

Comment: Esto no incluye las pestañas de búsqueda personalizables, ¿o sí?

Comment: @Mariano esta por verse eso

Comment: No soy muy fanático de la nueva *top-bar* (esconde demasiado a la ayuda), aunque la verdad me es indiferente... Eso sí, si pudiese de alguna hacer fuerza por que se incluyan las pestañas de búsqueda, estaría encantado. ¿Qué mejor que un sitio en beta, [el beta de mayor cantidad de preguntas/día](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), con i18n, para probar la implementación :-) ?

Comment: La captura incluye `Documentation`, no creo que vayamos a incluir `Documentación` en SOes, ¿verdad? ¿VERDAD? ¿ **VERDAD** ? *guiño, guiño, codazo, codazo*.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Jejeje, por ahora no. La documentación no será incluida al igual que Jobs.

Comment: @JuanM No veo que esto esté anunciado en ningún otro Meta. ¿Es algo exclusivo de SOes?

Comment: ¡Qué bien! Y por lo que veo todos tendremos rango de moderador para ver los reportes ;-)

Comment: @Mariano empezaremos con nuestro sitio y seguirán los otros sitios internacionales

Comment: @fedorqui jejeje, si lo deseas ;)

Comment: @JuanM Muy bien, ¡marcando el camino! Tenemos un CM que hace la diferencia.

Comment: es interesante saberlo, y aunque el bug que le comente en su dia queda disimulado aun no se al solventado, tambien lo publique en el meta de SOen y nadie en comparacion con los usuarios que tiene SOen dijo nada, pero quizas o yo no me explicara bien o no se puede solucionar facilmente por el diseño que tiene el sito o cualquier cosa, aun asi me encanta la esa nav. Saludos

Comment: Oh y sería bueno que le pusieran colores diferentes a SOes y a meta porque me reteconfundo...

Comment: @JuanM genial, estaba esperando con ansias esta nueva barra para personalizarla :) Aquí comparto [la versión oscura](https://gist.github.com/guzgarcia/8d5fa80c457d29ef6fe062cc33adf958) para que se use con Stylish.

Comment: @Toledano puedes personalizar la barra con Stylish (extensión de Chrome). Solo necesitas un par de líneas CSS.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía, ¿tienes algunos enlaces de preguntas en MSE sobre la personalización de la barra superior? _para ir preparando y haciendo pruebas en Stack Overflow en inglés_ :)

Comment: @fedorqui ¿No sería al revés? ¿El de hace 2 meses es duplicado o este?

Comment: @ArtEze si bien la fecha de publicación es un factor a considerar, no es necesariamente el primordial. La calidad del contenido por sobre todo. Aparte del hecho de que este es un anuncio oficial para la comunidad, en esta publicación se anuncia lo que en la otra se consulta si podría implementarse. Es correcto que esta sea la principal y otras se marquen como duplicado de esta pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano Listo, retirado mi voto de cierre, no lo tenía en cuenta.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía excelente! __Stylish__ tiene una extensión para Safari, que es el navegador que utilizó: http://sobolev.us/stylish/

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave La verdad solo necesitas inspeccionar la barra de navegación y mirar las clases CSS que tienen. Luego, solo es cosa de modificar o extender dichas clases con CSS propio.

Comment: @toledano Genial. Ya quisiera usar safari, tiene un soporte para ES6 impresionante. Lamentablemente aún no tengo una mac :P

Comment: Muchachos, mientras llega la nueva barra, [acá les dejo](https://gist.github.com/guzgarcia/0ca294496174089f607c99aace3f1d7c) la barrita actual pero enchulada.

Comment: Se ha tardado el lanzamiento de esta barra dado a que el equipo que estaba trabajando en la actualización fue desmantelado y ahora se volvió a crear bajo otro nombre.  Tendremos la nueva barra en unas semanas.  En cuanto sepa mas, le aviso.

Answer (score 4):

Parece que el gran día ya llegó :)

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Qué bien!

Comment: Debería incluirse la música de [Sergio el bailador](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MT12wFBE0A0) XD

Comment: @Rubén oh dios mío, ¿puedo reportar el videoclip como de muy baja calidad? :D

Comment: El vídeo está bloqueado por su importancia histórica ;)

Answer (score -1):

Ya tengo la nueva imagen y está padrísima (mola mucho):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que la barra va a cambiar, creo que estaría mejor mostrar el estilo sobre la barra de [so]

Comment: @Mariano por más que veo la nueva barra nomás no me convence (ni la de SO ni la que nos muestra toledano :P)

Comment: podria decirse que parece **stackoverbook** jejeje, me encantan esos colores