# Pruebas técnicas de la red de Stack Exchange - 3 de mayo 12:00 AM UTC

Tags: discusión

Les advierto que el **3 de mayo** tendremos una serie de pruebas internas en la red de Stack Exchange que durará no más de 20 minutos.  Durante este tiempo, los sitios se podrán acceder de manera "read only" lo cual quiere decir que no podremos preguntar, contestar, editar, o comentar en el sitio hasta que termine esta prueba.

La prueba tomará lugar a las **12:00AM UTC y hasta 20 minutos después**.  Cualquier problema, ya saben. ;)

Comment: ok, entendido ಠ_ಠ !

Comment: ¡Señor sí señor!

Comment: Proposito de la prueba?

Comment: @nacl igual será la [nueva barra de navegacion](http://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1779/la-navegaci%c3%b3n-nueva-se-aplicar%c3%a1-aqu%c3%ad-muy-pronto?cb=1)

Comment: no deberiamos cerrar esta pregunta como no esta claro lo que se pregunta?? :p (siempre hay alguien que arruina la fiesta)

Comment: Los 20 minutos más aburridos de mi vida.

Comment: @NaCl el propósito de la prueba es de asegurar que nuestros servidores web estén en orden y funcionando bien

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Si ocurre alguna incidencia, pueden ser los primeros 20 minutos que han tardado 30, o quizás 40 ...

Comment: De nuevo, es un lujo enterarse de algunas cosas acá antes que [en MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295285/304899)

Comment: Sugiero reemplazar 12:00AM, que es confuso, por 00:00:01AM o por 12:00:01AM.

Comment: Eso es el 2 de mayo a las 7 de la tarde, hora del Centro de México.